# Invisible element takes space and can't change table cell height

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a table with multiple rows. You can find the table [Here](http://foosball.ipdive.com/enterresult.html)

Select any item from the dropdown list and the table appers.

The table displays one team for each row. If the team has already been played with, the result of the match can be seen in the very right cell. If the match hasn't been played yet, there is instead a button and below the row there is a hidden row that appears after clicking on the button.

I have **two problems** with this table:

> **1)** Teams with the hidden row have bigger height then the others. But I am not able to change their height anyhow.
>
> **2)** Gaps between teams are 1px bigger for teams with hidden row. The problem is caused by the tr element. But it has zero size and
>   borders, so why does it take the space? I could set its display to
>   none and then take it away, but then it breaks my animation.

Both problems are connected with the hidden row, so I think that is the reason. But I really don't know how to fix it.

The expand/collapse is done with this js:

```
    if (this.dialogHidden) {
        this.enterDialog.css('height', '75px');
        this.enterDialog.css('border-style', 'solid');
        this.dialogHidden = false;
    }
    else {
        this.enterDialog.css('height', '0px');
        this.enterDialog.css('border-style', 'none');
        this.dialogHidden = true;
    }
```

Expand/collapse animation of enterDialog element is using transition (see following css code):

```
.enterDialog {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    padding-left: 10px;
    border: none 1px #FB667A;
    -moz-transition: height .5s;
    -ms-transition: height .5s;
    -o-transition: height .5s;
    -webkit-transition: height .5s;
    transition: height .5s;
    height: 0;
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Can you add some code to the question.  How are you hiding rows?

Comment: instead of `this.enterDialog.css('height', '0px');` can you make it `this.enterDialog.css('display', 'none');`? That way you don't have to worry about dealing with the properties of the element affecting anything else as it's effectively removed (it's not removed but as good as). It can be reset with `this.enterDialog.css('display', '');` Or change the class on it instead of applying styles directly which will also slim the script down a little (caveats).

Comment: I can do that, but that doesn't solve any of the problems above. The gaps are caused by tr element (try deleting it) and the rows are still bigger.

Comment: So then why not `this.enterDialog.closest("tr").css("display", "none")`?

Comment: I tried this before. It solves the problem number 1. But then my animation doesn't work, because you cannot animate with display: none. Some workaround exists, but I think if we solve problem 2, it will be connected to problem 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The Team with hidden row have a bigger height because the "Enter result" has 2% padding set. Add the following to "foosball.css":

   `.tdButton {
       padding-top: 0!important;
       padding-bottom: 0!important;
   }`
2. Teams with hidden rows have a bigger gap because the *dummy* TR is not actually hidden. Add the following to 'foosball.css':

   `tr.dummy{
      display: none;
   }`

And in enterResult.js line 157, change this:

```
if (this.dialogHidden) {
    // this.tr.removeClass('hidden');
    this.enterDialog.css('height', '75px');
    this.enterDialog.css('border-style', 'solid');
    this.dialogHidden = false;
}
else {
    // this.tr.addClass('hidden');
    this.enterDialog.css('height', '0px');
    this.enterDialog.css('border-style', 'none');
    this.dialogHidden = true;
}
```

to this:

```
if (this.dialogHidden) {
    // this.tr.removeClass('hidden');
    this.tr.css("display", "table-row");
    this.enterDialog.css('height', '75px');
    this.enterDialog.css('border-style', 'solid');
    this.dialogHidden = false;
}
else {
    // this.tr.addClass('hidden');
    this.tr.css("display", "none");
    this.enterDialog.css('height', '0px');
    this.enterDialog.css('border-style', 'none');
    this.dialogHidden = true;
}
```

Note that you will lose the row expanding animation. But if you used JQuery, the animation could be added in 1 line.

To add the animation, include Jquery to your page and then in enterResult.js line 157, replace this:

```
this.tr.css("display", "table-row");
```

by this:

```
$(this.dom).find("tr.dummy").slideDown();
```

and this:

```
this.tr.css("display", "none");
```

by this:

```
$(this.dom).find("tr.dummy").slideUp();
```

This should bring back the animation.

Comment: This works!!! Thank you. Do you what is that jquery line that would bring the animation back?

Comment: Sure, I have updated the answer to add the animation assuming you have included JQuery to your page.